# Types of LHA in the tibetan tradition

Tags: tibetan-buddhism, tibetan

According to Tibetan Buddhism, what does it mean LHA? (LHA body?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check out the second link (Tibetan Medicine Education Center) for more details.

From Nalanda Translation's "[Lha or is it La?](https://www.nalandatranslation.org/choosing-the-right-word/lha-or-is-it-la/)" page:

> Lha La (lha bla)
>
> Some confusion exists between two Tibetan words, sometimes used
> interchangeably:lha and la. The first, lha, is the Tibetan word used
> to translate the Sanskrit deva, meaning “deity,” “god,” or “divine.”
> This is also the term used in the Shambhalian sense of natural
> hierarchy: lha, nyen, and lu. (If we were to be more daring in writing
> this word like it is actually pronounced, we might spell it hla!)
>
> The word la (bla) literally means that which is “higher” or “above,”
> as in the word lama, the Tibetan translation of the Sanskrit guru
> (which literally means “heavy,” —heavy with good qualities, as the
> tradition explains). Lama Ugyen once explained lama as “one who looks
> down from above (la) with the love that a mother (ma) has for her
> children.” La is also a Pön term, meaning “soul,” “life force.”

From the Tibetan Medicine Education Center's page on "[Lha and Lha Ceremony](https://www.tibetanmedicine-edu.org/n-articles/lha-and-lha-ceremony)":

> THE LHA BODY
>
> What is the lha?
> “Lha” (bla) in Tibetan means ‘superior body‘, or
> ‘energy body‘. According to the Tibetan medicine and astrology
> concepts, between the physical body and the mind is the Lha body,
> which develops like a body copy, a shadow or reflection of the
> physical body. Therefore it is called subtle or energy body. It can
> hardly be seen by naked eye. The Lha body is very important to the
> health of the body/mind, as it always protects, nourishes and gives
> energy to the physical body, keeping it strong, stable and powerful.
> It gives psychological confidence, sense of ego and it plays a
> defensive role. The natural shape and form of the Lha body is exactly
> like that of the physical body and therefore they can be thought as
> dual bodies. When the subtle Lha body and the physical body are in
> correct position, it could bring harmony, the person feels well, has
> only few doubts and confusion, has a good concentration, a stable mind
> and a good immune system. If our physical body is healthy and in good
> condition, of course our mind and emotions are more stable and
> function well. But the modern stressful life, traumatic situations and
> many natural conditions can weaken the equilibrium between the
> physical body and the subtle Lha body, creating the conditions for a
> possible division, weakening, or loss of contact between the two
> bodies. This result of losing the Lha body is called: «lost Lha ». Lha
> can be damaged, become ill or leave the physical body, which could
> cause serious effects for the person.